# PHP foreach loop with JSON Data

Tags: php, json, api, foreach

I am using the [BandsInTown API](http://www.bandsintown.com/api/responses#event-json), and I'm trying to list all the event titles for a band. The code below works for the first title, but I need to look through all of them.  I tried a foreach loop I found on here, but did have any luck.  How do I show all the event titles for a particular band? I have been looking at previous questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248019/php-foreach-to-iterate-json-data).

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/Skrillex/events.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=MYID");
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data[0]->title;

// I tried this, but it didn't work
foreach($data->title as $title){
   echo $title;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be look for something like

```
foreach($data as $datum){
    echo $datum->title;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.,

```
foreach($data as $Events){
    echo $Events->title."<br>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
foreach($data as $item){
   echo $item->title; 
}
```